# split string and make array, regular expression

Tags: php, regex

```
$content = "[2][6][11]";
```

This i would like to split into an array with values [2], [6] and [11].

```
preg_split("/\[*\]/i", $content);
```

Wrong output: Array ( [0] => [2 [1] => [5 [2] => )

Any help what's wrong on the regular expression.

thanks.

Comment: `preg_split("/\h*[][]/", $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Comment: If it's guaranteed to be a number between the braces, this regex pattern will work: `/(\[\d+\])/`.

Comment: assuming there are only numbers in the braces: `preg_split("/(\[[0-9]+\])/", $content);`

Comment: @ThomasD. That won't work because you're not escaping the square brackets.

Comment: @jhmckimm thanks for the tip. forgot to format as code, thats why they didn't show ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds for this `split`:

```
$content = "[2][6][11]";
print_r(preg_split('/(?<=\])(?=\[)/', $content));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [2]
    [1] => [6]
    [2] => [11]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to test what are the characters around the position you want to find without matching them.

```
print_r(preg_split('~(?<=])(?=\[)~', $content));
```

Note that if you already know how your string is formatted, you can also use `preg_match_all` with a more simple pattern: `~\[\d+]~`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `preg_match_all` :

```
$content = "[2][6][11]";
preg_match_all("/\[.*\]/Ui", $content, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [2]
    [1] => [6]
    [2] => [11]
)
```